# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^s(\sqrt {n+1} - 2 \sqrt n + \sqrt {n-1})$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Convergence of $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^s(\sqrt {n+1} - 2 \sqrt n + \sqrt {n-1})$$

**Attempt:** $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^s(\sqrt {n+1} - 2 \sqrt n + \sqrt {n-1}) \sim \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^s( \sqrt n )$

As $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \dfrac {n^s(\sqrt {n+1} - 2 \sqrt n + \sqrt {n-1}) }{n^s( \sqrt n )} = 0$

$ \implies \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^s(\sqrt {n+1} - 2 \sqrt n + \sqrt {n-1})$ converges whenever $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^s( \sqrt n ) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{s+\frac {1}{2}}$ converges.

This happens when $s + \dfrac {1}{2}<-1$ or $s < \dfrac {-3}{2}$

Is my attempt correct?

Thank you for reading through!

Comment: Your asymptotic simplification is incorrect. It's not equivalent to whether $\sum n^{s+1/2}$ converges.

Comment: It just struck me too that the asymptotic simplification might be incorrect. If the expression was $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^s(\sqrt {n+1}  + 2 \sqrt n + \sqrt {n-1})$ instead of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^s(\sqrt {n+1} - 2 \sqrt n + \sqrt {n-1})$, do you think it would have been okay then? Thanks!

Comment: Then it would have been right (modulo a factor of $4$, which matters for asymptotic equality, but not for the $\Theta$ class, so not for convergence). But with the $-$, you need to find out how fast $\sqrt{n+1} - 2\sqrt{n} + \sqrt{n-1}$ approaches $0$.

Comment: Got it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider that
$$
\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n-1}=\sqrt{n}\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}+\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{n}}\right) 
$$
Also, we have that as $x$ goes to $0$:
$$\sqrt{1+x}=1+\frac{1}{2}x-\frac{1}{8}x^2+o(x^2)$$
and
$$\sqrt{1-x}=1-\frac{1}{2}x-\frac{1}{8}x^2+o(x^2).$$
Then, setting $x=\frac{1}{n}$, the sum is asymptotic exactly to 
$$\sum_{n\ge 1}n^{s+\frac{1}{2}}\left(2-\frac{1}{4n^2}-2\right)=-\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n\ge 1}n^{s-\frac{3}{2}}=-\frac{1}{4} \zeta\left(\frac{3}{2}-s\right),$$ 
which converges iff $s$ is smaller than $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: You're welcome ;)

Comment: @DanielFischer Here's how I tried it : $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^s(\sqrt {n+1} - 2 \sqrt n + \sqrt {n-1}) =  \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^s(\sqrt {n+1} -  \sqrt n - \sqrt n + \sqrt {n-1}) =  \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^s(\dfrac {1}{\sqrt {n+1} + \sqrt n} + \dfrac {1}{\sqrt {n } + \sqrt {n-1}})$ .

Comment: Then the above summation is $~\sum n^{s-\frac {1}{2}}$

Comment: @DanielFischer Is that okay?

Comment: @Wanderer Sign error, $$(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}) - (\sqrt{n} - \sqrt{n-1}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{n} + \sqrt{n-1}}.$$

Comment: @DanielFischer Oh! So, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^s(\dfrac {1}{\sqrt {n+1} + \sqrt n} - \dfrac {1}{\sqrt {n } + \sqrt {n-1}})$ .  After distribution, each summation,  is asymptotically similar to $~\sum n^{s-\frac {1}{2}}$. So, $s < \dfrac {-1}{2}$ is the condition for convergence?

Comment: @Wanderer : no, your one is a sufficient condition, meaning that both series converges. But indeed, you do not know what is the behaviour of the difference of two divergent series ;)

Comment: @Wanderer No, you should not distribute, since the two terms you subtract have the same asymptotics. Now Paolo's answer contains the correct result and way to it.

Comment: Happy Ending :P